# find all alternate paths shorter than a given distance

Tags: algorithm, graph

graph algorithm question for you.

I have a graph, used to represent a road network.  So there are cycles in it (a roundabout would be a trivial one).  Also some edges are bi-directional, some are uni-directional (one way streets).  Edges are weighted by their length.

Let's say I have two nodes and have already have computed the shortest path between them.  What I'd like to do is find all the other paths that connect the two nodes that are shorter than some distance X.  Call these paths the "alternates".

An example in ascii art is below, where I have labelled the edges with letters and the nodes with numbers.

```
         F
      5----6  
   E /      \ G  
    3--------4
   /    D     \
B /            \ C
 1--------------2
        A
```

Let's say I have the path covering edge A that goes from 1->2 and I want to find alternates.  One alternate to that path would be BDC, provided that its length is less than X.  BEFGC is another one.

Another example path would be BD that connects nodes 1->4.  An alternate to that one would be AC.

More requirements:

1. alternates should not include any part of the main path.  So if the main path is A, any alternate that contains A is not a valid alternate.  In the BD example above that connects 1->4, BEFG is not a valid alternate because it includes B which is in the main path.
2. alternates should not have internal cycles.  For example this alternate path would not be allowed for connecting 1->2:  BDGFEDC because it traverses edge D twice.

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem too different from finding regular paths, which you can already do. Dijkstra's algorithm supports finding all paths under a given length, and also shouldn't give cycles. Just run it on the subgraph without the primary path?

Comment: Yes, I second clwhisk. Find all path below the length X, remove these path segments and whatever you find in the remaining graph should satisfy your criterion. Isn't it?

Comment: yes that works.  silly i didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest path, you have a table which gives you, for each node, the shortest distance to that node from the source. I would delete from the graph the points on the shortest path, run Dijkstra's algorithm, and then do a depth first search from the target, terminating the search every time the path you are currently investigating becomes a cycle, or the sum of the distance on the path so far and the shortest distance from the current node to the source is more than X.

Every time you actually reach the source node you can print out the path so far.